# Install Homebrew from within a ruby script

Tags: ruby, bash, homebrew

I've created a ruby script that sets up a new mac.

Among other things it creates a `.bash_profile`, `.gitconfig` and configures various system settings such as displaying the full POSIX path as the Finder window title (super useful).

Mostly I'm running commands in backticks such as `` `defaults write com.apple.finder _FXShowPosixPathInTitle -bool true` `` the aforementioned full POSIX path as the Finder window title trick.

All this works just fine.

What I want to do is have this ruby script run the Homebrew installer too. The bash command for this is :

```
$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

However this doesn't work when called using backticks.

So my question is how do I run another ruby script (which the Homebrew installer is) from within a ruby script?

And more specifically how would I kick off the web based interactive Homebrew installer (well you have to press `return` at least once) from within a ruby script and for it's output to show in the terminal?

I know that I could rewrite this all as `bash` script but I'd really rather keep it all within ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's decompose what `$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"` actually does:

1. download, via curl, the homebrew install ruby file. Since the command is surrounded by `$()`, it executes the command and passes the output to ruby.
2. execute the script via Ruby. The `-e` flag instructs Ruby to execute the script from the command line instead of loading a specified file.

Since we know that it's a ruby script, we can just do the following:

1. using `Net::HTTP` or some other ruby library, download, the homebrew install file.
2. `eval()` or otherwise execute the homebrew ruby script.

Of course, `eval()` is dangerous, especially with untrusted input, but you're already essentially running eval on the script anyways with the install command provided.

In script form that would be:

```
require 'net/http'

homebrew_uri = URI('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install')
homebrew_script = Net::HTTP.get(homebrew_uri)
eval(homebrew_script)
```